# Need to refactor to if statements via ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

Hi guys first post and need the best way or solution to refactoring something which i think is ugly and normally not enough time is spent on it.

```
if(textInput.length > 0) {
    href = href + '&' + jQuery.param({ text: textInput.val()});
}

if(symbolDropdown.length > 0) {
    href = href + '&' + jQuery.param({ symbol: symbolDropdown.val()});
}
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Its fine... Everything else would make it really ugly...

Comment: is textInput a node list?  I'm just wondering what textInput.length is.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this.  Why do you think a ternary approach would make it better?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
href += (textInput.length?
            `&${jQuery.param({ text: textInput.val()})}`:''
        ) + (symbolDropdown.length?
            `&${jQuery.param({symbol: symbolDropdown.val()})}`:''
        )
```

Though honestly, if I was to refactor this code, I'd do something like:

```
const params = [], escPush = i => params.push(jQuery.param(i))

textInput.length && escPush({text: textInput.val()})
symbolDropdown.length && escPush({symbol: symbolDropdown.val()}))

params.length && (href += '&' + params.join('&'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with the data and map the `jQuery.param`. Later join with `&`;

```
href += '&' + []
    .concat(textInput.val() || [], symbolDropdown.val() || [])
    .map(a => jQuery.param({ symbol: a }))
    .join('&');
```

Comment: The first value goes under the key `text`